# Using Sympy, calculate a limit of sequence whose terms alternate sign

Tags: python, sympy

I am trying Sympy to find the limit of this sequence

```
               ((-1)**(n))*(2**(-n))
```

using the PyCharm debugger and the IPython console.

The python module is:

```
import numpy as np
from plotly.graph_objs import Scatter, Figure
from sympy import Symbol, srepr, limit_seq, oo
from sympy.abc import n

import plotly.plotly as py

py.sign_in('****', '****************')



sym_func = 1 + ((-1)**(n))*(2**(-n))

def rng_func(i):

    try:
        return 1 + np.power(-1, i)/(np.power(2,i))
    except ZeroDivisionError as e:
        raise ValueError('Invalid inputs') from e


class Sequence(object):

    def __init__(self, i):

        self.sum = 0
        self.dom = np.arange(1, i + 1, 1)
        self.rng = np.array([])
        self.is_positive = True
        self.is_alternating = True

        for i in self.dom:
            rng_val = rng_func(i)
            self.rng = np.append(self.rng, [rng_val])  
            self.sum += rng_val

        sign_array = np.sign(self.rng)

    for i in self.dom:

        if self.rng[i - 1] <= 0:
            self.is_positive = False
            break

    for i in self.dom:

        if sign_array[0] == -1:
            alt_sign = np.power(-1, i)
        else:
            alt_sign = np.power(-1, i-1)

        if alt_sign != sign_array[i-1]:
            self.is_alternating = False
            break


seq = Sequence(10)

data = [Scatter(x=seq.dom, y=seq.rng)]
fig = Figure(data=data)

py.image.save_as(fig, filename='plots/I3.png')
```

The IPython Console:

```
Connected to pydev debugger (build 171.4424.56)
Backend Qt5Agg is interactive backend. Turning interactive mode on.
import sys; print('Python %s on %s' % (sys.version, sys.platform))
Python 3.5.2 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Jul  2 2016,    17:53:06) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
IPython 5.1.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.

In[1]: limit_seq(((-1)**(n))*(2**(-n)), n)
In[2]: limit_seq((1**(n))*(2**(-n)), n)
Out[3]: 
0
```

My question is why does Sympy not return a value for the limit for In[1]: but does for In[2]:? The difference is the 1 versus -1 in the numerator.
Is there a different way to create an alternating sign in Sympy?

Answer (score 1):

As of now (SymPy 1.1.1), `limit_seq` does not support oscillating sequences such as those with `(-1)**n`. Its [documentation](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/series/limitseq.html#sympy.series.limitseq.limit_seq) says this in a somewhat technical way:

> The terms should be built from rational functions, indefinite sums, and indefinite products over an indeterminate n. A term is admissible if the scope of all product quantifiers are asymptotically positive. Every admissible term is asymptotically monotonous.

As a workaround, you can use this:

```
def mylimit_seq(seq, n):
    n_ = Dummy("n", integer=True, positive=True)
    L1 = limit_seq(seq.subs(n, 2*n_), n_)
    L2 = limit_seq(seq.subs(n, 2*n_ + 1), n_)
    if L1 == L2:
        return L1
```

Then `mylimit_seq((-1)**n * 2**(-n), n)` returns 0.

---

In a future release, `limit_seq` will work for such sequences. You can also get this functionality today by cloning SymPy from [GitHub](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/).

Comment: Interesting workaround, I see you are making the power term be always be positive or negative depending on the case, L1 or L2. To me this seems to be a general workaround for all alternating sequences. Thx

Comment: for me, I got NaN in the if statement because L2 = none.                                                                                     def mylimit_seq(seq, n):

    try:
        L1 = limit_seq(seq.subs(n, 2*n), n)
        L2 = limit_seq(seq.subs(n, 2*n + 1), n)
    except:
        return np.NaN

    if L1 == L2:
        return L1
    else:
        return np.NaN

Comment: Probably because your `n` wasn't declared integer, which prevents the simplification of `(-1)**(2*n)` into 1. If you had `n = Symbol("n", integer=True)` this wouldn't be a problem. But I edited the function so that now it doesn't need the user to declare the variable integer; it introduces an integer itself.

Answer (score 0):

I separated the series into even terms and odd terms, I reflected the series containing the odd terms about the x axis. This series becomes: 
    (1)*(2**(-n)), which then is identical to the series containing the even terms.

The function calculating the limit remains the same:

```
def mylimit_seq(seq, n):

    try:
        L1 = limit_seq(seq.subs(n, 2*n), n)
        L2 = limit_seq(seq.subs(n, 2*n + 1), n)
    except:
        return np.NaN

    if L1 == L2:
        return L1
    else:
        return np.NaN
```